# LibreOffice icons missing

Tags: permissions, libreoffice

I have been having a problem with my LibreOffice, all the icons have vanished.

[image: screen shot]

I have tried resetting everything but I did not make changes from the start so that did nothing. Then I tried to purge libreoffice through terminal but ran into another problem there with (13: Permission denied).

Answer (score 0):

Purge the libreOffice first :

```
sudo apt purge libreoffice
```

Install libreoffice again :

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

If your problem is not solved then try :

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk*
```